# How can I determine number of arguments to a function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given a function x in clojure how can I programatically get a count of the number of arguments?

eg:

```
(fn a [b c] ...) has has two arguments
(fn a [] ...) has has zero arguments
```

Comment: Give a look here maybe: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.reflect-api.html

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As I want to call a method which someones has 0 and sometimes has 1 argument

Comment: My use case for this is 'biting off' (consuming) items from a sequence using functions with different numbers of arguments.  (The sequence provides values that must not get used twice.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have access to the var that holds the function you can get the argument count by accessing its metadata in the following way:

```
(defn arities [v]
  (->> v meta :arglists (map count)))

(defn a [])
(defn b [_ _])

(map arities [#'a #'b])
;= ((0) (2))
```

`arities` will return a seq with all the arities for the function. This has the disadvantage that for a variadic argument vector (`[_ _ & _]`) it will return (4).

```
(defn c [_ _ & _])
(arities #'c)
;= (4)
```

This could be fixed by removing the `&` symbol from all the argument lists.

```
(defn arities [v]
  (->> v 
    meta 
    :arglists 
    (map #(remove #{'&} %))
    (map count)))

(arities #'c)
;= (3)
```

If you don't have access to the var, the following is a little function that I've used to detect the argument count of a function. It uses reflection so it's not the approach you might want to take if you need good performance. Also take into account that it relies on implementation details.

```
(defn n-args [f]
  (-> f class .getDeclaredMethods first .getParameterTypes alength))

(defn a [])
(defn b [_ _])
(defn c [_ _ & _])

(map n-args [a b c])
;= (0 2 3)
```

---

**EDIT**

After giving the answer another read, I realized the result 3 for a variadic function defined as `(defn x [_ _ & _] ,,,)`, is actually quite misleading since it's the same result you would get for a function with 3 arguments. The following version will return `:variadic`, instead of a specific number, for the argument vectors that contain the `&` symbol (except for the case `[&]` where `&` it's the actual argument name). As mentioned in a comment by *Jeremy Heiler* getting the argument count from the metadata only works if the value for `:arglists` is not manually changed.

```
(defn a [_])
(defn b [_ _])
(defn c [_ _ & _])
(defn d [_ _ _])
(defn e [&])

(defn variadic? [s]
  (and (some #{'&} s)
       (not (every? #{'&} s))))

(defn arities [v]
  (->> v
    meta
    :arglists
    (map #(if (variadic? %) :variadic %))
    (map #(if (sequential? %) (count %) %))))

(map arities [#'a #'b #'c #'d #'e])
;= ((1) (2) (:variadic) (3) (:variadic))
```

The reflection version for this is a little more complicated and it relies on more implementation details (i.e. "Is this or that function declared?" or "Does the function extend the class X?"), so I wouldn't recommend using that approach.

Comment: I'm still working through this. I didn't realise it was so complex... i would have thought that such a dynamic language had easy access to the argument list

Comment: It's worth noting that :argslist can be manually overridden: `(defn baz {:arglists '([boom])} [a b])` will result in `(:arglists (meta #'baz)) ;=> ([boom])`

Comment: I mention this not just because it *could* happen, but that it *does* happen. You'll see it a lot in clojure.core in functions that are defined before `defn`. Also, it is used to clarify the structure of variable arguments. (For example, optional arguments for `defn`.)

Comment: Another caveat: Say `(arities #'f1)` yields (2). Now create a new var to the same function using `(def f2 f1)`.  But `(arities #'f2)` evals to () and not (2) anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You could construct a function taking all arguments, putting them in a list and returning the count like so:

```
(defn arg-count [& rest] (count rest))
(arg-count) ;; 0
(arg-count 1 2 3) ;; 3
```

Comment: I think OP wants to be able to discover the arity of any arbitrary function.