# Is there an adapter that enables a function to ignore superfluous arguments?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a Clojure function, let's call it `anyargs`, that allows its function argument to ignore superfluous arguments. So that, for example,

```
((anyargs cons) :a [:b :c] :d) ; => (:a :b :c)
```

If the function argument took several arities, it would be good if the largest fitting one was chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to examine the function to see how many arguments it takes. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198633/2472391) covers ways to detect just that.

If you modify that answer slightly, you get the maximum number of arguments:

```
(defn n-args [f]
  (-> f class .getDeclaredMethods last .getParameterTypes alength))
```

This only works if the methods array is organized by the length of arguments, which on my system appears to be the case. If you really want to make sure,

```
(defn n-args [f]
  (apply max
        (map #(-> % .getParameterTypes alength)
             (-> f class .getDeclaredMethods))))
```

Then you can write:

```
(defn anyargs [f]
    (let [n (n-args f)]
        (fn [& args] (apply f (take n args)))))
```

This uses reflection, and it breaks down with variadic functions, but presumably you wouldn't use it with variadic functions. It's the best I can think of at the moment, aside from providing a wrapper that catches ArityExceptions and keeps retrying with fewer and fewer arguments until it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to hack it.

```
(defn max-arities [f] 
  (reduce 
    #(merge-with max % {(.getName %2) (alength (.getParameterTypes %2))})
    {} 
    (seq (.getDeclaredMethods (class +)))))


(defn anyargs [f] 
  (let [accept (if (instance? clojure.lang.RestFn f) 
                 identity 
                 (partial take ((max-arities f) "invoke")))] 
    (fn [& args] (apply f (accept args)))))


((anyargs cons) :a [:b :c] :d) ;=> (:a :b :c)
((anyargs +) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) ;=> 55
```

Answer (score 1):

Not cleanly, because Clojure does not expose the arity of its functions through a public API.

Given that you must know the arity of the function that you want to apply, it's easy enough to achieve this in the specific case, where n is the arity

```
#(apply f (take n %&))
```